# Postgresql query in 10 seconds

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to create a query that will run for exactly ten seconds ? I don't need real data just a way to run a query for a long time so I can test how the system works in that time.

I would prefer not to create a huge table and make a simple select just for this. Any tricks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`pg_sleep`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY):

```
SELECT pg_sleep(10);
```

But that will not generate any load on the system if that's your real goal.

Comment: Or a variation: SELECT generate_series(1,10000),pg_sleep(0.001)

Answer (score 4):

```
SET statement_timeout to '10s';
SELECT 1 FROM pg_class CROSS JOIN pg_class CROSS JOIN pg_class ...; -- be careful ;-)
```

Note that this will stress CPU and RAM, but not necessarily the disk.  If you want to stress the disk, you will probably just have to create a very big table.  To do that you could save the results of the query above or from any of the other solutions into a new table (`CREATE TABLE AS`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also run pgbench with -T switch.  So...

pgbench -i -s 10

pgbench -c 10 -T 10