# How to create long running select statement in postgresql for testing purposes?

Tags: postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Postgresql query in 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791578/postgresql-query-in-10-seconds)

I need to create really long running select statement to test job termination in my application. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM delay(10000);
```

Comment: pg_sleep will do the job, closed.

Comment: Please post and accept your own answer, then, so it doesn't show up in the unanswered list. Once SO lets you, but at your rep that should be right away.

Comment: Please, vote for closing. This is exact duplicate.